# Where can Sticky Session Cookies on PFC Instance captured

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have configured my.NetCore application with Sticky session Cookies and deployed it to PCF.

Where can I See captured Sticky Session cookies on PCF Instance??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform does not store this information. It's persisted through cookies, so if you look at your browser, you can see this information.

In order for persistent sessions to be used on CloudFoundry, you need to ensure that your session cookie name is `JSESSIONID`. If you're using a Java app, this is the default. Other languages may need to change the session cookie name so that it matches what the platform expects. If you examine the session cookie in your browser, you'll see the session id.

The CF infrastructure (Gorouter) will add an additional cookie called `VCAP_ID` which indicates the specific application instance to which your application is tied. With sticky sessions enabled, this `VCAP_ID` should be set on the first visit to your application and then should remain the same for subsequent visits.

You can examine the cookies with your browser's DevTools.

For more details on sticky sessions, also called session affinity, see this link: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html#sessions

Comment: thanks Daniel....I have done in mentioned below  Response.Cookies.Append("DPID", dpid);

Comment: Below code stores at attribute to Sticky session Cookie, Suggest is this correct
 Controller.cs
 Response.Cookies.Append("DPID", dpid); 
 In Manifest file 
env: 
 router.sticky_session_cookie_names:
 description: "DPID Sticky Session"
 default: [ "DPID" ]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a dotnet developer so I don't really know how you'd go about changing the session cookie name. If you're unsure, open a new question.